# Understanding control flow of recursive function that uses splicing

Tags: python, function, recursion, callstack

I seem to be unable to understand why it is, that once the terminating base condition is met in a recursive function, the function continues to call itself and go back up the call stack.

Here's an example recursive function written in Python 2.7:

```
text = "hello"
def reverse_string(text):
        if len(text) <= 1:
            return text
        return reverse_string(text[1:]) + text[0]
```

Using the [Python visualizer](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit), I understand how as the function calls itself with `reverse_string(text[1:])` and each frame is created as follows:

```
Frames
Global frame
text    "hello"
reverse_string  

reverse_string
text    "hello"

reverse_string
text    "ello"

reverse_string
text    "llo"

reverse_string
text    "lo"

reverse_string
text    "o"

Return
value   "o"
```

My question is this: why when the base condition is met (when `text = "o"`) does that trigger text[0] to start operating? I was thinking that all the code on that return statement/line would be working together at the same time, not understanding why `reverse_string(text[1:])` happens first, then `text[0]` — and again, why is `text[0]` activated when the base conditional is met?

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand your question but Python evaluates the expression from left to right and it has to evaluate reverse_string(text[1:]) before it proceeds to add text[0].

Comment: The question is: why does the function go onto the `text[0]` after the base condition is met? I'm not understanding how it goes from there down to `text[0]` and then back up through the frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may make more sense if you actually write out the calls and then what's returned from each of those calls. Starting from the uppermost `reverse("hello")`  (sorry -- shortened `reverse_string` for my lazy typing):

```
1: return reverse('ello') + 'h'
2:    return reverse('llo') + 'e'
3:       return reverse('lo') + 'l'
4:          return reverse('o') + 'l' 
5:             return 'o'
```

There are no more calls to make, so we work our way back up the call stack, returning the concatenated results as we go back up:

```
'o' is returned from 5
'ol' is returned from 4
'oll' is returned from 3
'olle' is returned from 2
'olleh' is returned from 1
```

...and that's returned as the result of the upper most call to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response! I guess I'm lacking the understanding regarding "There are no more calls to make, so we work our way back up the call stack, returning the concatenated results as we go back up" - why does it work that? Why, when the base conditional is met, doesn't the function essentially stop? I'm not getting what's making the function work its way back up the stack.

Comment: Remember that what makes the function recursive is that it calls itself. In that base case, there are no more function calls, so it just returns the value.

Comment: So essentially when `return text` happens, it's returning all the characters that were spliced off by `text[0]` each time `return reverse_string(text[1:]) + text[0]` was called?

Comment: Each of those return statements returns the results of calling itself without the first character of its argument and concatenates that first character onto the result of that recursive call.